# MVC Using a custom indexer with a EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, razor, editorfor, editorformodel

I have an EditorFor template that I call with an array of items (there may be a few) and I reference the indexes individually (not in a loop) so I can lay them out a certain way

> @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.SomeViewModels[0], "SomeTemplate")

all works fine but ideally I want to reference the array by a nicer indexer

> @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.SomeViewModels["Item to Find"], "SomeTemplate")

for better readability and some flexibility to cope if the index changes
so I was wondering if I could set up a custom indexer on the Model - like this

```
    public ObjecToReturn this[string TextToFind]
    {
        get
        {
                          return ObjectToReturn based on TextToFind
        }
    }
```

and it does work - and pulls the value through correctly however when I look at the Html the input fields all have names like `name=[Item to Find].AnswerValue` which I can see why but it messes up the post back

Just wondered if any clever person had worked out how I can send in `Model.SomeViewModels["Item to Find"]` to the EditorFor yet the underlying Html in the template reflects `Model.SomeViewModels[0]` (0 being the index of "Item to find" in the array) so the Postback works

Or maybe this is the wrong approach - I'm hoping I'm missing something straightforward.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

By default the `DefaultModelBinder` binds collections where the indexers start at zero and are consecutive. You can make this work by adding a hidden input for a `Index` property (note `Index` is not a property of your model - its just a special value used for binding collections). For example

```
<input type="text" name="SomeViewModels[ABC]" value = "" />
<input type="hidden" name="SomeViewModels.Index" value="ABC" />

<input type="text" name="SomeViewModels[XYZ]" value = "" />
<input type="hidden" name="SomeViewModels.Index" value="XYZ" />
```

The addition of the hidden input where the `value` attribute matches the indexer value allows the `DefaultModelBinder` to correctly bind the collection